# How to know what was filled in previos viewcontroller's textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have generated some data from database in a TextField according to that data i have to get another data in next ViewController but how can i know what was entered in that TextField and relate that to the unique id of my table in database.

Edited- The problem is that i have to load a list from database in a table view which i have done using sqlite3 singleton as we all know. Now this list is a suggestion type list to a textfield i mean the app starts with a textfield on screen which has some fixed text to be entered suppose like a list of bus stands  and when user click on textfield that tableviewcontroller will show with the list and it will get filled in that textfield. Now i have to use that bus stand name in another ViewController'S navigation bar's title. Is it clear. Please help.

Comment: Can you please explain more? And post your code or some charts? Hard to understand TextField, that data, ...

Comment: Please elaborate your problem. Explain properly what exactly you want to get. Post some snippets of your code and point out where you are getting stuck. You are saying that you need to get data on new ViewController. Thats means you don't have idea on how to X'fer data between ViewControllers. If thats the case please do mention that too in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a property of type NSString in the new ViewController where you want your data to be passed. For understanding lets name that property as strData and new view controller as NewVC.

Now I'm assuming that you are pushing to NewVC using segue. Now just define prepare for segue method as follows:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
       NewVC *objNewVC = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the NewViewController
        objNewVC.strData = TextField.text;
    }
}
```

Now you want this data to be used as NewVC's title then just write following is NewVC's ViewDidLoad()

```
self.title = strData;
```

If you still have problem with how to use segues for passing data between two view controllers then do mention it. I will edit my answer accordingly.